# Why do I get "Supplier Disabled" in my Altium BOM

Tags: altium, bom

I am trying to generate a BOM of my Altium project so that I can send it to the procurement people.

However, strangely when I go into `Reports` > `Bill of Materials` about half of the `Manufacturer 1` and `Manufacturer Part Number 1` fields have `"Supplier Disabled"` in them. I've included a snippet below:

[image: Supplier Disabled]

When I try to click on the supplier part number, it takes me to the supplier's website but searches for `Supplier Disabled`.
[For Example...](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=Supplier%20disabled)

I can't figure out why Altium is doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it was taking me to the suppliers website, the suppliers name was not quite correct (or at least how Altium expects it).

Specifically, the ones that had a problem had the supplier as `DigiKey` and Altium was expecting `Digi-Key`.

To change all of these wrong supplier names at once, I used `Parameter Manager` in the `Tools` menu.

Aditionally, you may have to enable the supplier in the `DXP Preferences` - `Data Management` - `Suppliers` page:

[image: Enable suppliers]